# How can the strace logs of the ever running binary from rcS can be logged?

Tags: embedded-linux

I am trying to do a profiling on my embedded Linux box. This is running a software.
I want to do a profiling on my software using strace.

The application is the main software that keeps running forever.
How can I run  the strace and log the outputs to a file.

In my rcS script.
I run the application like this
./my_app

Now, with strace.

strace ./my_app -> I want to log these outputs on a file, and I should be able to access the file without killing the application.  Remember this application never terminates.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a target filename, use the -p option to strace to specify the process ID of an already running process you wish to attach to.

Comment: What if that process never dies.

Comment: I want to keep tracing that particular PID and log it on to the file. Without killing the process, I should be able to see the logs.

Comment: Seems like you have neither tried this nor read the strace man page yet.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is actually right. Strace takes the -p option, which enables you to attach to a running process just by specifying the processes PID.

Let's say your 'my_app' process runs with PID 2301 (you can see the PID by logging into your device and us 'ps'). Try doing 'strace -p 2301', and you will see all system calls for that PID. You can throw it to a file by redirecting everywhere: 'strace -p 2301 > /tmp/my_app-strace'.

Hope this helps.